# Remove all columns where the entire column is null

Tags: python, data-cleaning, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a very dirty csv where there are several columns with only null values.

I would like to remove them. I am trying to select all columns where the count of null values in the column is not equal to the number of rows.

`clean_df = bucketed_df.select([c for c in bucketed_df.columns if count(when(isnull(c), c)) not bucketed_df.count()])`

However, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2213215314329625>", line 1
    clean_df = bucketed_df.select([c for c in bucketed_df.columns if count(when(isnull(c), c)) not bucketed_df.count()])
                                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If anyone could help me get rid of these dirty columns, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated]**: Just realized it is about pyspark!

It is still simple! A concrete example (idea heavily borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322445/how-to-drop-all-columns-with-null-values-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)):

**Creating a dummy dataset**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlf

main= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

main["E"]= np.NAN
main["F"]= np.NAN

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(main)
```

**Function to drop Null columns**

```
def drop_null_columns(df):
  
    """
    This function drops columns containing all null values.
    :param df: A PySpark DataFrame
    """
    
    null_counts = df.select([sqlf.count(sqlf.when(sqlf.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
    to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v >= df.count()]
    df = df.drop(*to_drop)
    
    return df
```

**Outcome**

```
df_dropped = drop_null_columns(df)
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer will work, but will run `df.count()` for each column, which is quite taxing for a large number of columns. Calculate it once before the list comprehension and save yourself an enormous amount of time:

```
def drop_null_columns(df):
  
    """
    This function drops columns containing all null values.
    :param df: A PySpark DataFrame
    """
    _df_length = df.count()
    null_counts = df.select([sqlf.count(sqlf.when(sqlf.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
    to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v >= _df_length]
    df = df.drop(*to_drop)
    
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think these lines could help: my case does not precisely answer to the original question. If we need to keep only the rows having at least one inspected column not null then use this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce

inspected = df.columns
df = df.where(reduce(or_, (F.col(c).isNotNull() for c in inspected ), F.lit(False)))
```